# How can I have x-axis ticks that show ticks scaled in powers of ten?

Tags: plotting

[image: plot]

I am having trouble achieving this effect with on the x-axis. Does anybody have an idea how I can achieve this effect?

Comment: As a slight correction to kglr's comment: the "number theory" version of the logarithmic integral is expressed as `LogIntegral[x] - LogIntegral[2]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Kanye! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
LogLinearPlot[{PrimePi[x]/(LogIntegral[x]-LogIntegral[2]), 
  PrimePi[x]/(x/Log[x])}, {x, 2, 10000000}, GridLines -> {None, {1}}]
```

[image]

Thanks: @J.M.iscomputer-less for the `LogIntegral[2]` correction.